# Date calculator in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, datetime

So what I want to do is create a function that can take in input date, calculate X number of days/weeks/months later (or before) and output the resulting date. The trick being to remember to calculate leap years, months that have more or less than 30 days, etc. I'm pretty new to Visual Basic so I don't really know where to start with this. I have some ideas rolling around in my head but nothing that I can really put into code. I don't just want someone to write all the code for me, but rather give me some ideas about where to start etc.

What i'm thinking right now is to have the user click a button (btnCalc) that would prompt the user to enter the date they wish to calculate from and anther inputbox that asks how much time they wish to add/subtract from that date. These values would be passed to the CalculateDate function that would preform the calculations. I was thinking about having the user enter a negative number if they wished to get a date before the date entered and so I could have an if /else clause to determine which calculation to do based on whether the number was > or < 0. This is where I get lost. I don't know how to tell visual basic what a date is or how to decided how many days are in the months or to watch for leap years. Any help would be appreciated here, and please tell me if im going in the complete wrong direction with this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Joseph, I think Visual basic having some inbuilt date functions , I used it long back

Comment: "Adding 3 months to a date" is an extremely complicated operation to define.

Comment: That's what I was thinking SLacks. The more I thought about coding the function the more complicated it was sounding.

Answer (score 2):

The `DateTime` class has all of these methods already on it.

```
result = theDate.AddDays(1)
result = theDate.AddDays(-100)
result = theDate.AddMonths(42)
result = theDate.AddYears(-10)
...etc...
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) for further details.